# Qt Enterprise VirtualKeyboard works but with error "not installed"

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick, virtual-keyboard

I'm getting an Error in QtCreator with Qt Enterprise VirtualKeyboard. I built and installed it as per description on http://doc.qt.io/QtVirtualKeyboard/build.html and deployment-guide.html. 
I can compile and run the Example project and it works as espected. But in QtCreator the statement following statement gets the "Error-Line" with the Message the module would not be installed.

```
import QtQuick.Enterprise.VirtualKeyboard 2.0
```

The Error in the tooltip is "QML Module not found".

Funnily the following

```
import QtQuick.Enterprise.VirtualKeyboard.Styles 2.0
```

doesn't throw an error.

So I had a look in the import path. The QTDIR\qml\QtQuick\Enterprise\VirtualKeyboard folder only has a Folder Styles with the Styles-Plugin in it. No files in the VirtualKeyboard. I suspect the missing files aren't correctly coppied to this folder.

I tried to find out which files exactly are missing but failed. Has somebody a running installation without these errors, who can tell me exactly what files are missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try to switch to Version 1.3 instead of 2.0? Maybe you built the wrong version, as 2.0 seems to be still in preview state..

Comment: The virtual keyboard plugin is installed to `plugins/platforminputcontexts`; does it exist there?

Comment: @Mitch Yes there are the two dlls (debug / release), but no other files like qmldir, don't know if that is needed

Comment: @Stanley If I install 1.3 only the **qtvirtualkeyboardplugind.dll** gets updated, a known Problem in the Qt-Forum. Also the Error is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run the app in the Release mode? We also got the same error in the Debug mode, but by switching to the Release mode, everything goes very well! We still don't know what's going on there, but at least this works.

Answer (score 0):

So for me it was the usage of `minimalegl` QPA that lead to QT not finding the plugin/module. Switching to `eglfs` solved the problem.

TLDR: `my_app -platform eglfs` works while `my_app -platform minimalegl` does not.